# Parse error trying to install Tensorflow with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, installation, conda

I have been trying to install tensorflow by using Anaconda Prompt so I have python 3.7, but there's this error I can't find how to fix:

OK EDIT: I am new here so I will try to learn and post correctly. This error continues, it is present even if I try to update navigator:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I can't even create an environment through the navigator, the option "CLONE" is not available and in the create menu there doesn't appear any location and the "CREATE" button is disabled. I checked and I am not behind any proxy. I have searched for an answer to this but none of the solutions I found have worked with me. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: please include more output from the error, perhaps you're just missing some dependencies. you might check those also

Comment: A few things: First, don't use the base environment for development. Second, don't use pip in a Conda environment unless you're aware of the particular risks involved (see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/). As for the unexpected error, has anything noteworthy happened to your Conda installation?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same error and I have solved this by **Installing [OpenSSL](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/) in Windows.**

After installation you may disregard the step in *creating OpenSSL keys* and just proceed to test your anaconda if it works.

This worked well to me.